# Vue 2 proxy to Vue 3 on localhost

Tags: vuejs2, proxy, vuejs3, vite

My team and I are currently migrating from vue2 to vue3 on our legacy project. Our strategy is to migrate page by page using CDN routing to the right asset in production. This works fine.

The problem is for dev. This is my current configurations

Vue 2 + vue-cli

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
...
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '^/test': {
          target: 'http://localhost:8090/test',
          changeOrigin: true,
        },
      },
    },
...
}
```

Vue 3 + Vite

```
//vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
...
    base: '/test'
...
})
```

```
// router.ts
export default createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory('/test'),
})
```

As you can see in my screenshot below, the first call to `test/` works fine and returns the `index.html` file, but the next calls to get the assets do not

[image]

I think the problem lies into my `vue.config.js` in the way I proxy my requests...